# Struts html text tag color attribute

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, struts, tld

I would like to add a color or style attribute specifically to the below line but I keep running into TLD issues

```
<html:text property="xxxx" readonly="true" color="#C0C0C0"/>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/FinanceFee.jsp(617,22) Attribute color invalid for tag text according to TLD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css style overrides

```
<html:text property="xxxx" readonly="true" style="color:#C0C0C0;"/>
```